# parse text from html markup

Tags: c#, html

I have approximately 27,000 entries of the following markup in a conventional text file :

```
<li class="active-result group-option" data-option-array-index="4">Microsoft Power BI</li>
```

The only thing I need from the above is  (in this case)

> Microsoft Power BI

Using C#, I tried string split options (reading from a file called `select.txt`), however, I have not yet managed to accomplish this task. Any ideas?

Comment: Are the entries line separated?

Comment: are the class names all the same?

Comment: @prospector yes, all of the same class. The only thing that differs is the text itself, as well as `data-option-array-index`.

Comment: @Adam They're not, unfortunately. I took it from Chrome using `Inspect Element` and copied into the text file. Maybe there's a better solution for this anyway.

Comment: Why don't you just get the text between the first `>` and the second `<` char?

Comment: There are couple questions on [C# parse HTML](https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+parse+html) - please make sure to update your post with approaches you've tried (along with link to article/question describing the approach) and short not why each did not work in your concrete case.

Comment: are there other elements instead of LI in the file? UL? Body?

Comment: Well, thanks for downvoting my post. I now can't give proper credits to those that answered featuring a working solution by upvoting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The most ideal way to do a small thing like this is regular expressions.

In the top of your file add:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Then use this regex to capture all the values you want

```
string input = ReadSomethingFromFile(); // input is the raw data you are trying to read
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, "<li class=\"active-result group-option\"[^<]+>([^<]+)</li>");

// Loop through all matched elements
forEach(Match m in matches) {
    string capturedString = m.Captures[0].Value;
    // Do something with capturedString
}
```

If you are planning to add more functionality in your program later, you should use a proper html parsing library. But if you are only going to do this one thing, regex is the simplest option.

Comment: I appreciate your answer! However, the output is `<li class="active-result group-option" data-option-array-index="4">Microsoft Power BI</li>`.

Comment: For 27,000 entries I don't think Regex is the right solution.

Comment: @jdweng not necessarily if this is a one-time analysis. 27 000 entries is still doable.

Comment: @Jony I didn't test this so you may be right. Are you sure that the value of `capturedString` is not `Microsoft power BI`? This should be correct, according to the MSDN documentation Match.Captures should contain the results from the capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

I know somebody is going to give me negative points for using xml to read html.  But in this case it works nicely.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = "<li class=\"active-result group-option\" data-option-array-index=\"4\">Microsoft Power BI</li>";
            //use only for reading from string.
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(text);

            List<string> data = new List<string>();
            //for reading from file use XmlReader.Create(filename);
            XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(reader);
            while(!xReader.EOF)
            {
                if(xReader.Name != "li")
                {
                    xReader.ReadToFollowing("li");
                }
                if(!xReader.EOF)
                {
                    data.Add(xReader.ReadInnerXml());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd give you an upvote, however, my post got downvoted and thus I cannot  do so. Sorry!